Complex logical expression (wrong or as intended?)
I have a 3 part logic (A or B and C). Logically if A is true then true, or if B and C is true then true; But here is the error

if (A or B and C) -> should return true
if [ 1 -eq 1 ] || [ 2 -eq 2 ] && [ 3 -eq 30 ]; then echo "true"; else echo "false"; fi

returns false (should be true because "and C" is false at the end of the expression, is this a bug? or am I missing something?)

if (B and C or A) -> does return true
if [ 2 -eq 2 ] && [ 3 -eq 30 ] || [ 1 -eq 1 ]; then echo "true"; else echo "false"; fi

returns true (as should be)


Edit 2-
So is the best way going forward is to use parentheis around all the AND logic?
if [ 1 -eq 1 ] || ( [ 2 -eq 2 ] && [ 3 -eq 30 ] ); then echo "true"; else echo "false"; fi


Use a truth table to set up the A,B,C combinations (all eight of them) and verify that your shell code produces the correct output for every combination. Remember that logically, AND has a higher precedence (binding) than OR, so A or B and C is equivalent to A or (B and C)

But my point is the 2 lines above give opposite result depending on the order that I write the logic A or B and C vs B and C or A.

@TrầnQuốc-Bình that's also what the duplicate asks and the answers there explain: they have equal precedence in bash and therefore left associativity comes into play: so A || B && C == (A or B) and C while B && C || A == (B and C) or A

Thank you, but when I read the answers in the duplicate asks, I assumed the && and || symbols were used in the command mode.
Command1 && Command2 woud be different to && used in an if [ block ];
Really, if the if blocks does not follows the Logical AND before the OR then thats a very big issues for writing scripts.

@TrầnQuốc-Bình if does not impose any special "mode". It's if command and [ is a command, not syntax nor mode. [ … || [ … && [ … are three commands in "the command mode" (whatever this means).

@TrầnQuốc-Bình For what you want to do, shell arithmetic seems better: if (( 1==1 || 2==2 && 3==30 )); then echo "true"; else echo "false"; fi. There (i.e. inside (( ))) && and || behave as you expect.

@KamilMaciorowski - Thank you, and thank you. Really I have not made aware of shell arithmetic until now. Everytime I search the internet it is full of commands if [ ]; and was not even aware of these if (( )). So thank you once again.

@TrầnQuốc-Bình Well, if you asked "(how) can I make && and || work as I expect in this conditional of mine?" then shell arithmetic would be an answer and you would probably get the answer quite quickly. Instead you asked "wrong or as intended?" and "is this a bug? or am I missing something?", to which the linked question has answers. The shell arithmetic is not an answer to this and it was not obvious that maybe it will help you the most. The lesson is: fellow users tend to answer what you ask, not necessarily what you need; asking the right question is crucial (but not always easy).

@KamilMaciorowski, thank you. I know most people would ask general questions as to how to fish, rather than give me a fish. So my example were trying to simplified my code to highlight the point of AND OR logic in the if [] construct. But sometimes in the real code we need both arithmetics and string comparisons and even commands like -f file exists. How would that all ties in to make the bese way to write clean codes?
